# how to reference a multi column primary key in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE `rfid_reader` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`lattitude`, 'longitude') REFERENCES `ROBS`.`location`(`lattitude`, 'longitude') ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

The above command results in an error. Do i have to refence lat->lat and long->long seperately? I though a foreign key always had to reference a primary key.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: The error is because you have single quotes where you want backticks (or no quotes at all).  This is a simple typographical error and I vote to close.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Thank you so much